Definition of convex set in a complex vector space and related reference books
I have learned that the definition of a convex set is as follows:

Let $V$ be a real vector space and $M$ be a subset of $V$. If for any $x,y\in M$ and $\alpha \in [0,1]$, $\alpha x+(1-\alpha)y\in M$, then $M$ is a convex set.

I am not sure that if $V$ is a complex vector space, is the definition of a convex set still:  if for any $x,y\in M$ and $\alpha \in [0,1]$, $\alpha x+(1-\alpha)y\in M$, then $M$ is a convex set? Since I think $\alpha$ may belong to $\mathbb C$.
And are there any recommended reference books on convex sets in a complex vector space dealing with questions such as Hahn-Banach in a complex vector space?
Basically, I am beginning to learn functional analysis, but my book always deals with just real cases, and I don't know much about complex vector space.

Yes, the definition of convex sets only uses $\alpha \in [0, 1]$, regardless of whether you’re in a real or complex vector space. If you allow $\alpha \in \mathbb{C}$, that would define an affine subspace instead of a convex set.

Note that $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$ so $\mathbb{C}$ can be identified with $\mathbb{R}^2$ for the sake of convexity.

It's not hard to show that, for a complex functional $f$, its real part $\mathrm{Re}f$ is a real functional. Conversely, if $g$ is a real functional , then $f(x)=g(x)-ig(ix)$ is a complex functional.
